# JQUERY doesn't recognize JSON response from request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to do multiple image upload, I get the response in the control tab network all working good uploading but once I want to use the response its printing 'undefined' in the console

My response from network :

```
{"msg":"<div class=\"alert alert-success\"><i class=\"fa fa-check\"><\/i> The file 5ac6060c8fc14 (1).jpeg successfuly uploaded.<\/div>","all_images":[{"name":"5ac6060c8fc14 (1).jpeg","dir_name":"f1197245ac6060c8fc14 (1).jpeg"},{"name":"5ac6060c8fc14_1_192x192.jpeg","dir_name":"abf70115ac6060c8fc14_1_192x192.jpeg"},{"name":"5ac6060c8fc14_1_192x192.jpeg","dir_name":"8b2f2625ac6060c8fc14_1_192x192.jpeg"},{"name":"5ac6060c8fc14_1_192x192.jpeg","dir_name":"bb2d7165ac6060c8fc14_1_192x192.jpeg"},{"name":"5ac6060c8fc14.jpeg","dir_name":"b1538ee5ac6060c8fc14.jpeg"},{"name":"5ac6060c8fc14_1_192x192.jpeg","dir_name":"f73d4195ac6060c8fc14_1_192x192.jpeg"},{"name":"5ac6060c8fc14_1_192x192.jpeg","dir_name":"6a2a2c35ac6060c8fc14_1_192x192.jpeg"},{"name":"5ac6060c8fc14.jpeg","dir_name":"bfb8ac35ac6060c8fc14.jpeg"}]}
```

My code:

```
$('#upload_files').easyupload({
        url: 'sources/requests/ajax.php?type=upload-files',
        on_upload_before: function (info) {
            $('#status_1_text').html('');
            $('#progress_1').fadeIn(150);
            $('#status_1,#status_1_total').css({width: 0});
        },
        on_progress: function (progress) {
            $('#status_1').css({width: progress.progress_file + '%'});
            $('#status_1_total').css({width: progress.progress_total + '%'});
            $('#status_1_text').html('Sending files ' + progress.current_file +
                            ' / ' + progress.total_files + ' ');
        },
        on_upload_file: function (data) {
            $('#status_1').css({width: 0});
            $('#status_1_text_total').html(data.msg)
            $('#gallery').html(data.all_images)
        },
        on_upload_finish: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('#progress_1').fadeOut(500);
            $('#status_1_text_total').append('All files ' +
                            'successfully uploaded to the server.');
        }
    });
```

When I print `data.msg` its showing but the images not working, even if I write `console.log(data);` its returning `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Hey what ever the response you get is a valid json response and i do not see an error i even tried to print in my console and it just works fine

[image: console screenshot]

If you still have an issue it probably with how you are handling the response form the request you could either provide the response type as JSON and parse the data.

If you still tend to get this error request you to console.log the data and check the value that you are receiving and provide it as an edit for your question to help us better understand the problem.

Comment: Once I print console.log(data) its returning undifined